# Dijkstra algorithm on a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I have to create an N * M matrix and fill it up with values between 0 and 9. One of the values should be "A" which is the starting point of the graph, and I should find the shortest path to the value "B" (both of these are generated at a random position of the matrix). If the value is 0 it counts as an obstacle, and 2 < N, M < 100.

I have to print out the exact route of the shortest graph and the total cost of it. Also, the problem has to be solved by Dijkstra's algorithm.

I've haven't gotten past filling up the Matrix. I store the values in a 2D String array, but I think I should use different arrays or maybe Maps for storing the positions of key values such as the start and endpoint. I've been thinking on this for 2 days now because I'm a total noob in Java and not much better at programming in general. I'm mainly looking for guidance on how to store the datas and what should I actually store in order to get to the end because I think I overcomplicate the problem.

This is the matrix generating part of the code.

```
int N = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3,7);
int M = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3,7);
int J = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,(Math.min(N, M))/2);
int K = 0;
int aPosX = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,N);
int aPosY = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,M);
int bPosX = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,N);
int bPosY = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,M);
String[][] matrix = new String[N][M];
int[][] map = new int[N][M];
int shortestPath = 10;
int currentPosX,currentPosY;
int shortestPosX, shortestPosY;

public void generateMatrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            K = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10);
            matrix[i][j] = String.valueOf(K);
        }
    }
}

public void createStartAndFinish(){        
    matrix[aPosX][aPosY] = "A";
    matrix[bPosX][bPosY] = "B";
}

   
}
```

This part finds the lowest cost adjacent tiles and steps on them but id does generate an out of bounds exception. I'm also aware that it has nothing to do with Dijkstra algorithm but this is my starting point.

```
public void solveMatrix(){
    visited[aPosX][aPosY] = true;
    currentPosX = aPosX;
    currentPosY = aPosY;
    
    while (!matrix[currentPosX - 1][currentPosY].equals("B") || 
            !matrix[currentPosX + 1][currentPosY].equals("B") || 
            !matrix[currentPosX][currentPosY - 1].equals("B") ||
            !matrix[currentPosX][currentPosY + 1].equals("B")) {
        
        if(currentPosX > 0) {
            if(!visited[currentPosX - 1][currentPosY] && Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX - 1][currentPosY]) < shortestPath) {
                shortestPath = Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX - 1][currentPosY]);
                shortestPosX = currentPosX - 1;
                shortestPosY = currentPosY;
            }
        }
        if(currentPosX + 1 < N){
            if(!visited[currentPosX + 1][currentPosY] && Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX + 1][currentPosY]) < shortestPath) {
                shortestPath = Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX + 1][currentPosY]);
                shortestPosX = currentPosX + 1;
                shortestPosY = currentPosY;
            }
        }
        if(currentPosY > 0){
            if(!visited[currentPosX][currentPosY - 1] && Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX][currentPosY - 1]) < shortestPath) {
                shortestPath = Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX][currentPosY - 1]);
                shortestPosX = currentPosX;
                shortestPosY = currentPosY - 1;
            }
        }
        if(currentPosY - 1 < M){
            if(!visited[currentPosX][currentPosY + 1] && Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX][currentPosY + 1]) < shortestPath) {
                shortestPath = Integer.parseInt(matrix[currentPosX][currentPosY + 1]);
                shortestPosX = currentPosX;
                shortestPosY = currentPosY + 1;
            }
        }
        
        visited[shortestPosX][shortestPosY] = true;
        currentPosX = shortestPosX;
        currentPosY = shortestPosY;
        
        System.out.println(shortestPosX + " " + shortestPosY + " " + shortestPath);
        shortestPath = 10;
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: If you did not even achieve the simpler part without the "portal" please focus your question on that.

Comment: "I've haven't gotten past filling up the Matrix." and "I just tried to find the closest neighbours of the start and always step at the lowest cost neighbour." seem like a contradiction. Please clarify.

Comment: Fair, I'm editing it.